# Fetching data from database using SELECT with WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, select

i have two files : test.html and test.php

in the html file i have a link , when the link clicked it will pass a parameter to angular controller that contain a function which will post the variable to  test.php file using $http.post

in my php file i receive the value and i need to execute database statements based on this value .

when i use insert statement it works fine :

```
$my = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$id = $my->id;

require 'database.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `my_database`.`persons` ( `person_id`   ) VALUES(?)";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($id));
```

the value added to the database successfully.

but when i use SELECT statement like this :

```
$my = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$id = $my->id;

require 'database.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM persons where person_id = ?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($id));
$data[] = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print json_encode($data);
```

the result of the query will be: [false]

note that when i define the value of person_id manually , the select statement work will and return values .

i mean as follows :

```
$q->execute(array("17"));
```

any solution ?

Comment: and what if you added `my_database` to `persons` the same way you did in the INSERT? or add `$data = array();` on top of `$q->execute(array($id));`.

Comment: Sounds like `$id` is not getting set as you think it should. What does `var_dump($my)` reveal?

Comment: *The truth Sam* @JayBlanchard are we ready for it?

Comment: *I was born ready Ralph. I'm sorta' awesome like that.* ;) @Fred-ii-

Comment: thanks but nothing works ! what make me crazy when i insert $id it works ! but when i use select doesn't work !! moreover, when i pass id manually in the select  it works ! so its clear that my select statement doesn't deal with $id !! why ?!

Comment: Did you do `var_dump($my)` as I asked before?

Comment: yes i tried , but the same problem , dear , as $id worked for INSERT this mean that i received the parameter well, the problem when the SELECT take $id !! it return false .